# Reduce number of Outlets? Swift

Tags: swift, outlet

I've started learning Swift and started off with some simple Games. But every time (depending on the Game) my Code would look like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var B1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B8: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B9: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B10: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B11: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B12: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B13: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B14: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B15: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B16: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B17: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B18: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B19: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B20: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B21: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B22: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B23: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B24: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B25: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B26: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B27: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B28: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B29: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B30: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B31: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var B32: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var L1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L5: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L6: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L7: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L8: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L9: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L10: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L11: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L12: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L13: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L14: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L15: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L16: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L17: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L18: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L19: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L20: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L21: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L22: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L23: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L24: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L25: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L26: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L27: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L28: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L29: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L30: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L31: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var L32: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var C1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C4: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C5: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C6: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C7: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var C8: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var randomPin1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var randomPin2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var randomPin3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var randomPin4: UIButton!
```

I am pretty unhappy with this, is there a way to use those Buttons (or whatever type it is) without creating an '@IBOutlet weak var *name*: *Type*!'? Like with an identifier and then using the identifier to access a Button? Or is that just the normal way to do this? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: it seems like you are going wrong this like you want repeat job, I would suggest please think about it and use: `UICollectionView` and `UITableView`.

Comment: general note: whenever you start having to include numbers in your variable names you should think about using a collection / array instead.

Comment: @luk2302 yeah thats a great idea, thats a good guideline thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use IB Outlet Collections and store these instance in arrays:

http://nshipster.com/ibaction-iboutlet-iboutletcollection/
https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-an-iboutletcollection-in-ios-78cfbc4080a1

Comment: Nice! I didn't know there were OutletCollections :) That was just was I was looking for, thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept the answer if it's you were looking for ;)

Comment: Will do when it lets me ;)